# What is the best way to loop with very short and accurate interval in Unity?

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine

We want to create a special video player in Unity and we need to draw the video frame according to its FPS, like 30, 50, 60 or even 120. The video frames are decoded from native plugin and their corresponding textures are returned to Unity. So we should draw and update the texture in Unity infinitely with a short and accurate loop interval such as 33.3ms for 30FPS, 16.7ms for 60FPS, 8.3ms for 120FPS, and so on. In order to achieve this, which of the following methods should we use?

- `FixedUpdate()` with variable `Time.fixedDeltaTime`
- Coroutines with `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealTime()`
- `InvokeRepeating()`
- Some other methods that we don't know yet.

We cannot use `Thread`s with `Thread.Sleep()` because we should call some Unity APIs to do the rendering that are limited to be called on Unity's main thread.

We have tested `FixedUpdate` and Coroutines but it seems their intervals are limited by the frequency of `Update()`, which is related to the device's screen refresh rate. For example, if we tested it on an OnePlus 7 Pro, since the refresh rate is 90Hz, the `Update()` is called per 11ms approximately. Then if the video's FPS is 30, since 33 can be divided by 11, it's OK. But when we switch to a 60FPS video, the rendering interval cannot be 16.7ms, but 22ms instead, which makes the video looks laggy.

So which is the most accurate and stable way to loop with such a short and variable interval?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve the results you want in Unity, as all looping updates are tightly bound to the core of the engine, which you cannot edit or modify. All of the above methods you described run in C++ in code like this.

```
//Pseudocode
void Loop()
{
   while(true)
   {
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      Render();
      while(FixedUpdate())
      {
          DoPhysics(); //Wait for allphysics simulation to end
      }
      Update();
      RunCorutines();
      LateUpdate();

      sw.Stop();
      if(sw.Elapsed() <= 1000f/Application.targetFrameRate)
          Thread.Sleep(1000f/Application.targetFrameRate- sw.Elapsed());
   }
}
```

That being said, you can use `Thread.Sleep()` on the main thread! But this would not give you the consistency you want.

**Possible Solution**

What I would suggest (if this is possible for you) use a separate thread with the decoder to keep decoding in with sync in the framerate you are targeting, and separate rendering pipeline using the Dispatch pattern.

```
public class MainThreadDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static MainThreadDispatcher Instance;
    public static object VideoLock = new object();
    public Texture2D latestFrame;
    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    //You might have to use byte array instead of Texture2D or Copy the Texture created on other thread
    public static void Dispatch(Texture2D frame)
    {
        lock (VideoLock)
        {
            MainThreadDispatcher.Instance.latestFrame = frame;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {        
        lock (VideoLock)
        {
            Render(latestFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Usage
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var texture = Decoder.Decode();
        lock (MainThreadDispatcher.VideoLock)
        {
            MainThreadDispatcher.Dispatch(texture);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(WaitForTargetFPS());
    }
});
```

This would ensure the following.

- You are always rendering the latest possible frame.
- If video is 120fps and you can only display 30fps, the video would not be 1/4 speed.
- Video would still look smooth even if threads are not synchronized (but you can account for that in the Decoder thread)

Comment: Rendering the latest possible frame is easy but I don't want to skip any frames. The solution you suggested is still limited by the frequency of Update() if I don't misunderstand.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot overcome that in Unity. You are limited by the engine